# Sharedworkers in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, shared-worker

I'm working on an application which uses a websocket from a SharedWorker. According to the documentation, SharedWorkers should be supported in current versions of Chrome and Firefox. However, when I try the example from this GitHub, it works perfectly in Chrome, but nothing happens in Firefox:
https://github.com/goeddea/scratchbox/tree/master/test_cases/shared_webworkers

Is this example wrong, or does Firefox lack some relevant support for SharedWorkers, or maybe it has something to do with using "http://localhost" (SharedWorkers only work with examt same protocol, host and port)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox pushed Quantum before multiprocess worker support was finished.

I believe this is the current issue https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1438945

The dom.ipc.multiOptOut setting should revert to single process and allow shared workers to work again.

Comment: We have worked around this issue since then, but it sounds as if this could have been the problem. So I'll accept this.